# When is the ideal time to finish Shnayim Mikra?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, shnayim-mikra

Regarding Shnayim Mikra v'echad targum, [Halachipedia](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shnayim_Mikra_V%27Echad_Targum#When_Should_it_Be_Read) says this:

> Some have the practice to read a little bit every day and complete it day Shabbat. [37]

They also say:

> Some have the practice to do the Shenayim Mikrah on Friday afternoon. [44]

And:

> One should finish Shenayim Mikra V'Echad Targum by Shabbat lunch. [45]

So, from what I gather the *latest* time is by your Shabbos day Seudah. But, what I am wondering, is what is the ideal time? Is finish Shabbos ideal, or is finishing before shabbos better? Is finishing on Friday better than Thursday (as apparently some are makpid to do it on Friday)?

What's the best way to do it, min hamuvchar?

Comment: Doesn’t the Talmud say עם הצבור? When is the tzibur finishing?

Comment: Just to clarify: If you did not finish by Shabbos lunch, you should still finish anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, each one of these options has someone that says it's min hamuvchar.

Shulchan Aruch 285:4

> מצוה מן המובחר שישלים אותה קודם שיאכל בשבת ואם לא השלים קודם אכילה ישלים אחר אכילה עד המנחה וי"א עד רביעי בשבת וי"א עד שמיני עצרת (דהיינו בשמחת תורה שאז משלימים הצבור) 4)

> The 'choicest' way to perform this commandment is to complete the reading before the Shabbat meal. If you missed out on the opportunity to do so, you have until Mincha. Others say until Wednesday the week afterwards; while others even say you have until Shmini Atzeret (Rem"a: Shmini Atzeret is

The Biur Halacha brings that Erev shabbos is best, either to start or to finish (2 shitos)

> קודם שיאכל - המגן אברהם הביא דעות דמספר הכונות משמע דלכתחלה ישלים בע"ש ורק כשהיה אנוס ישלים בשבת ובב"י ומגיד מישרים משמע דלכתחלה יתחיל בע"ש וישלים בשבת ועיין מה שכתבנו במ"ב בשם האור זרוע ותר"י והגר"א:

And lastly, the Mishna Berura adds that if not Erev shabbos then at least before Shachris on shabbos

> שישלים אותה וכו' - וכדאיתא במדרש שצוה רבי את בניו אל תאכלו לחם בשבת עד שתגמרו את כל הפרשה. ומ"מ פשוט דאין לעכב מחמת זה האכילה עד אחר חצות וכדלקמן בסימן רפ"ח דזהו רק מצוה בעלמא ולכתחלה מהנכון אם לא קרא שנים מקרא ואחד תרגום בע"ש להשכים בשבת בבקר ולקרא השמו"ת קודם הליכתו לבהכ"נ [כן איתא באור זרוע ריש הלכות שבת וכ"מ בתר"י ריש ברכות ע"ש]